# Command Arguments field in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, command-line-arguments

I try to pass some arguments to the program using Visual Studio Community 2015.
I add some input in the Configuration Properties - Debugging - Command Arguments.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "args:" << args << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < args; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "argv[" << i << "]=" << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
args:1
argv[0]=c:\users\john\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe
```

Why the input in the "Command Arguments" field is ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the build configuration you set the command line for is the one you are running? VS allows different command line arguments to be set for each build (debug/release and platforms by default).

Comment: That was it. By default, the Property Pages chooses the x64 Platform and the IDE is choosing x86. I was paying attention only to the Debug/Release choice. Thanks!